# Activation and expiration for VB.net application

Tags: vb.net, licensing

A customer asked me for a way to add a license key and expiration date to an app; he would like to assign them to the program and then generate the setup. Which is the most secure and common way to do it? The program is written in VS.net 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options I can think of

Create a license key that encodes the expiry date into the key and read this when the application runs:

```
Dim ExpiryDate as Date = LoadLicenseFile 'extracts the hashed expiry date from the file
If ExpiryDate < DateTime.Now then Application.Exit
```

Create a web service to handle activation requests and connect to the web service when the applications runs.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer; i would prefer the first option but was asking me how to realize it: I can create a local license file on which i can put a crypted content like:
md5("APP_NAME"+"EXP:2013/12/31") . My problem is that I am not able to check, for every other date different than expiration day, if the license is expired or not.
Which could be the best way to crypt the date and check it?